# Dependency injection : static parameters and services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this service that will be injected to some other controllers.

It needs a service, and a connection string that is taken from a configuration file.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  public MyService(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, string connectionString){
     //...
  }
}
```

I would like `IService1` and `IService2` to be injected, but `connectionString` to be specified manually. I can't get my head around a way to work this out, the examples I saw were either massively complex, or just not what I wanted to achieve.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cfg = new MyConfiguration();   
    Configuration.Bind("config", cfg);
    var connectionString = cfg["myConnectionString"];
    services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>(/*what can I do here?*/)
}
```

Can this be achieved simply ?

Comment: I usually just register the configuration object so I can inject it in the contstructor of whatever needs it.

Comment: This is indeed a solution, but I was pretty sure there would be a way to achieve this specific thing

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren while that can work, people with knowledge of the framework tend to advise against injecting `IConfiguration` directly into classes.

Comment: Might be so, I tend to wrap it down my own configuration objects such as IDatabaseConfiguration and ISmtpConfiguration though to avoid havnig other implementations know of the configuration keys.

Comment: Which is good. There is also the `IOptions<T>` pattern built into the framework. Referemce [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I did now know of those, it seems to be a simple way to do what I'm usually doing.

Comment: Please note that you [should prefer _not_ injecting](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t) `IOptions<T>` into application components

Comment: MS Says "ASPNET CORE avoids Static". The example given in Thread.CurrentPrincipal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to the service provider within the factory delegate.

Resolve the other dependencies and inject the static variable when initializing the service.

```
//...
var connectionString = cfg["myConnectionString"];
services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(_ => 
    new MyService(_.GetService<IService1>(), _.GetService<IService2>(), connectionString));
```

In the above example `_` in the factory delegate is a `IServiceProvider`, and `GetService<T>` extension method is used to resolve the other services provided they are also registered with the service collection.

The factory delegate will be invoked the first time `IMyService` is requested.

As an alternative, referencing [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

And assuming for example a *settings.json* file

```
{
  "myConnectionString": "value1_from_json",
}
```

consider using the `IOptions<T>` provided by the configuration extension.

create a class to store the desired configuration.

```
public class MyConnections {
    public string MyConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

refactor the class to depend on `IOption<MyConnections>`

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private string connectionString;
    public MyService(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, IOptions<MyConnections> options){
        connectionString = options.Value.MyConnectionString;
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

and configure it on start up

```
//...

services.Configure<MyConnections>(Configuration);
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Comment: Can I use this method to register services with circular dependencies ? For example, can I register  `IService1`, with  `_.GetService<IService2>` and right after, register  `IService2`  with  `_.GetService<IService1>`  ?

Comment: circular dependencies tend to break the system so I do not understand why you would want that

Comment: Because this is also my case, I should have been more specific. My  `IService1` needs  `IService2` in it's constructor, and vice-versa

Comment: @ArthurAttout That is a design issue and is destined to fail. You need to review your design choice in that matter. That is also a totally separate issue to what was originally asked.

Comment: Oh .. Okay, I'll fix that. I though dependency injection was made for that purpose though ..

Comment: @ArthurAttout I advise you look up what circular dependency is and why it is bad. DI was not meant to solve that. It can help you discover it (when things break) but it is not a solution to it. Good design is the only solution to the circular dependency problem.

Comment: @Nkosi I think inlining your comment about `IOptions<T>` would make answer even better...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok I'll try to work it into the answer. Was only addressing the immediate problem. but i guess I can provide the additional details.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like Nkosi suggests and use a factory that creates the service. This however has the drawback that this is very explicit and will require you to always adjust the object creation whenever your constructor signature changes (for example when you need different dependencies).

A more proper solution in the ASP.NET Core world would be to use the options pattern. What you do is basically instead of requiring a connection string to be passed to the constructor, you create a new configuration type that configures your service. You can then configure this object using the options pattern.

This would look like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(IService1 service1, IService2 service2, IOptions<MyServiceOptions> serviceOptions)
    {
        var connectionString = serviceOptions.Value.ConnectionString;

        //...
    }
}

public class MyServiceOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString
    { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your startup, just register your type and configure the options:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(options => {
    options.ConnectionString = "connection string";
});
```

If you place the configuration for your connection string into a separate configuration section, you could even do this:

```
services.Configure<MyServiceOption>(configuration.GetSection("MyService"));
```

Assuming your configuration looks like this:

```
{
    "MyService": {
        "ConnectionString": "…"
    },
    // …
}
```

Comment: Is this still a good practice, since @Steven said that injecting `IOptions<T>` is not preferred ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout I don’t really agree with the contents of the linked article. The article assumes that options are always created from a single configuration source at the composition root. That is simply false and ignores large parts of the options pattern. Also, as for validation: Even if you skipped the options pattern and used the configuration object directly, you still have the same possible problems about unconfigured settings. You should validate them in the constructor, and then there is no real different to using options.